# Django tagging migration to GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, tagging

I have a Django app that use a django-tagging. I need to port this application to GAE. So, the main problem is to migrate tagging part. It has a complicated model, that should be rewritten to work with Google store. I think tagging is very popular django app and someone has the same problem before. Has someone a rewritten model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Nick's post about [tagging blog posts](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/10/Blogging-on-App-Engine-part-5-Tagging). It covers all main tagging issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [modified django-tagging](https://bitbucket.org/legutierr/django-tagging-multidb/overview), probably it might work.